# recycler view is not scrolling smoothly on lollipop

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView which displays an image, a few textviews and 2 imageButtons.
The program works absolutely fine for android 4.4.4 and below but it isnt scrolling smoothly on lollipop.

There is some sort of lag/jerk that feels while scrolling in lollipop.
I searched to reduce the scroll speed by overriding the fling method, bu there appears to be no such method for my problem.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {



@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(view, viewType);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(view, viewType);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder.Holderid == 1) {
        final MenuDescription menu = listOrder.get(position - 1);


        Glide.with(context).load(menu.getFlag_path()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_order_now).fitCenter().into(holder.image);

    } 
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != listOrder ? listOrder.size() + 1 : 0);
}


}
```

}

Comment: whats the approx size of images that are being loaded. I faced the same issue when I tried to load heavy image in each of recyclerview items

Comment: Currently i am not downloading images. I am simply using placeholder images. but it will be around 320 X 180 in dimensions.

Comment: oops i meant image file size. if possible try to draw empty imageviews or with some image which has very less filesize and see if this is issue. just a suggestion.

Comment: I am currently not downloading any image. Instead I am using placeholder image which is 1.20 KB in size and 120 X 120 in dimensions. Still the problem persists.

Comment: hmm could be it because of glide ?  Can you try to comment out image views and see what happens or statically attaching single image without glide and see what happens ???

Comment: Tried that as well. Still no improvement. On some devices(like nexus 4) it is working fine , but on some it's not.

Comment: possible to share the minimal code to debug this issue in github or elsewhere ?

Comment: figured out what i was doing wrong. Was setting font for every textview in recycler view item inside the adapter which consumes way too much RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.
I was setting the font for very textview from the adapter class which seems to consume way too much RAM. Instead setting the font using setTypeface method, I created a custom textview and setting its typeface from XML.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-extend-androids-textview-to-use-custom-fonts/

Comment: I have read this article and haven't found why it may optimize RAM. I usually use TextViews and create a singleton class that loads a font into memory. After that apply this font to any TextView, no memory leaks or something.